# Get string inside string

Tags: java, string

So I have this string:

```
String myString = "Welcome, your drive today to the LAX will be (45+ min). Enjoy your drive!";
```

What is the best way to go about getting the `45` as a separate string? And this string could sometimes have more than one number in it, Example:

String myString = "Welcome, your drive today to the LAX will be (45+ min). You should arrive about (11:10 am). Enjoy your drive!";

But I only want to get the one what has 45+ min and separate out the `+ min` so that `45` is my only string.

Comment: `indexOf("45")`? Substring? Or will that number change? Different units? If so, Regex?

Comment: Regex seems to be your best bet

Comment: Is the rest of the string fixed, or are there other variables?

Comment: `System.out.println(myString.replaceAll(".+\\((\\d+).+\\).+", "$1"));`

Comment: `myString.replaceAll("\\D", "");` ;)

Comment: Do you want to extract all the number from the string ? or any specific number?

Comment: If you want all number from string then use `String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");`.otherwise clearify the statement?

Comment: Can you please explain the exact requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure out my answer after a lot of trial and error. If you have a better way please comment it, I don't mind changing my accepted answer.

```
String text = "Welcome, your drive today to the LAX will be (45+ min) and the tolls will cost ($2.50). Enjoy your drive!";

tripMiles = getNumberFromString("(?i)(\\d+)\\s+ min", text);

public static double getNumberFromString(String value, final String s)
{
    double n = 0.0;
    Matcher M = Pattern.compile(value).matcher(s);

    while (((Matcher)M).find())
    {
        try {
            n = Double.parseDouble(((Matcher)M).group(1));
            if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "Number is : " + ((Matcher)M).group(1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            n = 0.0;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
Java Predefined character classes for regular expressions.
    .   = Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
    \d  = A digit: [0-9]
    \D  = A non-digit: [^0-9]

```
String myString = "Welcome, your drive today to the LAX will be (45+ min). Enjoy your drive!";

//Replace all non digit characters with empty space so only numbers will be there.
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\D", "");
System.out.println(myString); //this displays only numbers.
```

Comment: So with this method if there is every any other numbers in the string it won't work? Example: `String myString = "Welcome, your drive today to the LAX will be (45+ min) and the tolls will cost ($2.50). Enjoy your drive!";` So yours method would return both numbers into one string?

Comment: @Jayce This is why you need to be more precise with your requirements. Just going by your sample, `str = "45"` would suffice. If you want a flexible solution, you need to describe the *pattern* you're trying to match.